# Module of vector bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, modules, vector-bundles

If E→M and F→M are two vector bundles over manifold M, then $C^{\infty}$(E,F) is a $C^{\infty}$(M) module. I am confused about this claim for the operation of module.
To f$\in$$C^{\infty}$(E,F) and g$\in$$C^{\infty}$(M), how could g operate on f? f is from E to F while g is from M to R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p:E\to M$ and $q:F\to M$ be the projections, so $f$ is a smooth map $E\to F$ such that $qf=p$ and $f$ is linear on each fiber.  Define $g\cdot f$ by $g\cdot f(x)=g(p(x))f(x)$ for $x\in E$ (here $g(p(x))\in\mathbb{R}$ and we are multiplying $f(x)$ by it using the vector space structure of $F_{p(x)}$).  It is then straightforward to verify that $g\cdot f\in C^\infty(E,F)$, and this makes $C^\infty(E,F)$ a module over $C^\infty(M)$.

Comment: Sorry I think the $g\cdot f$  here is not linear from $E_x$ to $F_x$

Comment: If $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$, then $g\cdot f(\lambda x)=g(p(\lambda x))f(\lambda x)=g(p(x))\lambda f(x)=\lambda g\cdot f(x)$ since $p(x)=p(\lambda x)$ and $f(\lambda x)=\lambda f(x)$.  Additivity of $g\cdot f$ is similar.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand why p($\lambda$x)=p(x), and g$\cdot$f($ x_1+x_2$)=g(p($x_1+x_2$)(($f(x_1)+f(x_2)$) which is not g$\cdot f(x_1)$+g$\cdot f(x_2)$

Comment: Scalar multiplication and addition are operations _within_ a single fiber of $E$.  So if $x\in E$, $\lambda x$ is in the same fiber of $E$.  And $x_1+x_2$ is only defined if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are in the same fiber, in which case $x_1+x_2$ is also in that fiber.

Comment: Thanks, I just messed up the definitions.